# jQuery - end setinterval after X rund

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little slider im working on which is almost there im jsut having some trouble with me jQuery.

---

**So first off:**
I want my slider to reset after the interval has run x amount of times.
It was my understanding that the following would work but it doesn't seem to take. `6000, slides, function() { homesliderend();`

so lets say `slides = 2` set interval should call `homesliderend();` but it doesn't the interval just keeps running.

---

**Second Issue:** I'm also trying to get it to add 100% to `lengther` every 6 seconds. But instead of adding 100 each time its just setting it to 100 its not multiplying.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  "use strict";

  function homesliderend() {
    $(".lengther").animate({
      left: "0%"
    }, 500);
  }

  function homeslider() {
    var slides = $(".slide.t-align").length,
      lwidth = slides * 100,
      n = 0;

    $(".lengther").css("width", lwidth + "%");

    setInterval(function() {
      var tn = n + 100;
      $(".lengther").animate({
        left: "-" + tn + "%"
      }, 500);
    }, 6000, slides, function() {
      homesliderend();
    });


  }
  homeslider();
});
```

Comment: You need to cancel your `setInterval` yourself, it doesn't have a parameter to just run it an x amount of times.And seconly, `tn` is always going to be `100` because `n` is `0` and doesn't change.

Comment: You need to call `clearInterval()` yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The `setInterval` will not stop automatically, you need to clear the interval to stop it.

Also you need to increase the value of `n` to increase the left param

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    function homesliderend() {
        $(".lengther").animate({
            left: "0%"
        }, 500);
    }

    function homeslider() {
        var slides = $(".slide.t-align").length,
            lwidth = slides * 100,
            n = 0;

        $(".lengther").css("width", lwidth + "%");

        var interval = setInterval(function () {
            var tn = ++n * 100;
            $(".lengther").animate({
                left: "-" + n + "%"
            }, 500);
            //if the last item is slided then stop the animation and run homesliderend
            if (n == slides) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                homesliderend();
            }
        }, 6000);


    }
    homeslider();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Arun, I updated your answer was a couple of mistakes.

Only thing I have now is when it reaches the end instead of just going straight to the end it adds another 100 on first so I end up with some blank space for a bit